# stripslashes in Multi-Dimensional array

Tags: php

How can i stripslash all values in multi-dimensional array?

i.e.

```
$my=array(
  'title'=>'http:\/\/example.com',
  'group'=>array(
             'first'=>'lo\"\"la',
             'second'=>'antver\"',
          ),
   ......
);
```

Comment: [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive)

Comment: May we ask about the root cause of the corrupted data?